# How will the popularity of hosted apps be determined?

Tags: support, contest

In the contest blog post:

> - We will look at the number of requests for your API key. Was your application used by a lot of people? Or at least a reasonable amount?

How does this work for apps that run off a central server, since all the requests will be coming from one IP address? How will you know the number of individual users using the app?

Would it help if we passed along the `User-Agent` header from the client when querying the API?

Do we need to turn over server logs?

Comment: I''ll send you some User-Agent headers and server logs. What would you like them to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [contest announcement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-contest/).

> The entire Stack Overflow, Inc team
>   will ultimately decide the winners
>   based on order of awesomeness. And
>   lest you think we don’t know awesome
>   when we see it, we built Stack
>   Overflow. I’m just sayin’. (But
>   seriously, please understand that our
>   decisions will be based on a variety
>   of factors, some of which may be
>   entirely subjective.)

All the bullet points in the announcement are examples of things we will consider when debating the **awesomeness** of various [app]s amongst ourselves.  They're listed because they're worth drawing attention to, not because there's some minimum "cutoff" value an [app] must achieve in each to even be considered.

Comment: So basically it doesn't matter?

Comment: @George - it matters, but not enough to document how we're tracking it.  We'll handle unusual cases ourselves, no need for an [app]s developer to do anything.

Comment: So you'll let me know if you need further information then? Great! What a relief :)